# Replying from Gmail with custom POP3 settings and auto selecting the associated custom SMTP settings

Tags: gmail, pop3, smtp

I set up Gmail to add a POP3 and SMTP server for sending mail. Whenever I get mail to that new address though, and I press on reply it still tries to reply by default by using my `@gmail.com` address.

Is there a way that when I get mail to that new POP3 account, that it will auto select the associated SMTP account?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes**.

You need to add that email address as an account that you can send from (if you haven't aleady done that).

Then you need to turn on the setting to reply as the account sent to.

Both settings can be found under `Settings | Accounts and Import`.

[image: screen shot]

See also: [Gmail support](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&ctx=mail&answer=22370)

Comment: I think I'm missing the option for this: "Then you need to turn on the setting to reply as the account sent to."   I have the SMTP settings working already, just not auto selecting.  Where is it located?

Comment: Found it in Accounts and Import.  Thanks!

Comment: Updated answer and added a screen shot.